# Nesting an application inside OS X subview

Tags: macos, nested, subview

I'm looking for a way to embed another application into my own view.

The business reason is that the company has many small [Electron apps](http://electron.atom.io/) (basically a small portable web program with a self-contained browser) that the company wants to embed inside an OS X program. These Electron apps would ideally integrate and display inside a subview seamlessly, so they look like little web frames inside our larger program.

I think programatically it would be easiest to open another program as a subview, but I'll take whatever I can get. Maybe even capturing it's NSWindow somehow. ([Electron source is available so it is easily discoverable](https://github.com/electron/electron/tree/master/atom/browser).) Maybe a way to dock the other program inside mine, or (getting more desperate) finding its view and sending commands to constrain it's size and location on top of mine.

So far all I've found says it is not really possible.  I've found I can take the more desperate course. I can launch a process, find its view, and position it inside a spot on my display; when the window is moved or the content is scrolled send messages to move the other window. But that isn't really integrated, the menu stays separate, etc., but I cannot incorporate it.

Any ideas or helpful implementation details?

EDIT 1: Thanks for those responses. How about if we could have the electron apps expose their NSWindow somehow? Could that be leveraged?  I'm thinking the application could send messages and (somehow, not sure exactly) to set the parent window inside this one.  In Windows API it is much easier since you can call SetParent on anything, even items inside different processes. But Cocoa seems more difficult.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really a thing you can do in Mac OS X. Applications are not "composable" in the way you're hoping for - while it is possible to share a view with a subprocess under certain very specific circumstances (e.g, Safari or Chrome tab renderers), this requires the subapplication to be written in a very specific way to permit that. It's not something that would be feasible in the situation you're describing.

If you have access to the source of these Electron apps, consider combining them into a single overarching Electron application. Alternatively, if it's not possible for these applications to coexist within a single Electron app, you may want to consider using something like [Chromium Embedded Framework](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef) to build your wrapper application; note, however, that this may require you to implement parts of the Electron framework yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that. `Cocoa` requires you to have only one `NSApplication` instance per UI app. So you will to `fork/exec` out new process and launch your applications.

If you can recompile the source code then you can create custom subclass of `NSApplication` and use that custom class in all the applications or you can create `NSthread` of other applications without `NSApplication` instance and go from there.

Comment: Several parts of this answer are definitely not right. You can't run multiple instances of NSApplication in threads, and NSEvent doesn't have any application here that I'm aware of.

Comment: @duskwuff I didn't mean create NSApplication instance in threads, updated my answer. NSEvent I remember you could capture mouse events globally but how exactly you would use that I'm not sure

Comment: Using fork/exec to start new processes would launch the subprograms as separate applications, which the OP has already said they tried doing (and wasn't sufficient for their needs).